# Linear transport equation and characteristics

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let us assume $c>0$ and consider the PDE
$$
(\ast) \ \begin{cases}
u_t+c(x)u_x = 0, \qquad (t,x) \in (0,T)\times(0,1) \\
u(0,x) = g(x) \\
u(t,0) = f(t)
\end{cases}
$$
Suppose that
$$\dot x(t) = c(x(t)), \quad x(0) = x_0$$ has a unique solution $x \in W^{1,\infty}(0,T)$. How can we write down explicitly a solution formula for $(\ast)$ using the method of characteristics?

I'm guessing that the explicit solution should be something like
$$
   u(t,x) = \begin{cases}
    g(\beta^{-1}(\beta(x)-t)), \ & (t,x) \in (0,T)\times (0,1), \ t \le \beta(x), \\
    f((t-\beta(x)),  & (t,x) \in (0,T)\times (0,1), \ t > \beta(x);
    \end{cases}
$$ with $\beta(x) = \int_0^x \frac{dy}{c(y)}$, but how do you rigorously prove it with the assumptions given above?

Comment: Your equation is overdetermined. The only initial condition needed is $u(0,x)=g(x)$. This equation is covered on page 24 of Peter Olver's [Introduction to Partial Differential Equations](https://www.usb.ac.ir/FileStaff/3223_2019-10-28-13-12-55.pdf)

Comment: @K.defaoite The third line is a boundary condition, not an initial condition

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find out that $u(t,x(t))$ is constant, the value determined by the point where the boundary with a condition is intersected.

The solution method requires that the strip is filled with characteristic curves that either intersect the segment $(t,x)\in\{0\}\times[0,1]$ or the ray $[0,\infty)\times\{0\}$. This follows from continuous dependence of ODE solutions on the initial point. Further $c>0$ implies that there are no characteristic curves that intersect with both boundary parts.

If $f(0)\ne g(0)$ you get a discontinuity in the solution, so it is questionable if this will give a solution at all.

Comment: Thanks. But what's the explicit formula for the solution? I'm guessing something like $$
   u(t,x) = \begin{cases}
    g(\beta^{-1}(\beta(x)-t)), \ & (t,x) \in (0,T)\times (0,1), \ t \le x, \\
    f(\beta^{-1}(t-\beta(x))),  & (t,x) \in (0,T)\times (0,1), \ t > x;
    \end{cases}
$$ with $\beta = \int \frac{1}{c}$, but how do you prove it?

Comment: That would only be true if $c$ were constant $1$. But here $c$ is variable, but as it only depends on $x$, all characteristic curves are parallel, time-shifted versions of each other.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the comment to fix the mistake. My guess is $$
   u(t,x) = \begin{cases}
    g(\beta^{-1}(\beta(x)-t)), \ & (t,x) \in (0,T)\times (0,1), \ t \le \beta(x), \\
    f(\beta^{-1}(t-\beta(x))),  & (t,x) \in (0,T)\times (0,1), \ t > \beta(x);
    \end{cases}
$$ with $\beta = \int \frac{1}{c}$. Is this right? If yes, how can one prove it?

Comment: You now need to compare $β(x)$ and $t$ as the separating condition. Also note that $β$ transforms space into time and that $f$ takes a time argument. /// This should then be sufficient. All arguments are mentioned somewhere on this page, one only needs to streamline their assembly.